# unexpected error deploying firebase functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-tools

i did successfuly to ( "npm install -g firebase-tool" and "firebase init functions")
and i got an error and no reason given in the line of code.

```
PS C:\flutter_projects\login_register_desing> firebase deploy --only functions

=== Deploying to 'login-register-design'...

i  deploying functions
Running command: npm --prefix %RESOURCE_DIR% run lint

> lint
> eslint .

+  functions: Finished running predeploy script.
i  functions: preparing codebase default for deployment
i  functions: ensuring required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled...
i  functions: ensuring required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled...
i  artifactregistry: ensuring required API artifactregistry.googleapis.com is enabled...
+  artifactregistry: required API artifactregistry.googleapis.com is enabled
+  functions: required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled
+  functions: required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled

Error: An unexpected error has occurred.

Having trouble? Try again or contact support with contents of firebase-debug.log
```

i guess i must add to code lines about hosting here. help me please what should i write if im right?

```
{
  "functions": [
    {
      "source": "functions",
      "codebase": "default",
      "ignore": [
        "node_modules",
        ".git",
        "firebase-debug.log",
        "firebase-debug.*.log"
      ],
      "predeploy": [
        "npm --prefix %RESOURCE_DIR% run lint"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: The error message suggests you should look in firebase-debug.log for more information. What does it say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`An unexpected error has occurred` is a generic error message which can be caused by various reasons,sometimes updating firebase tools to the latest version fixes the issue. You can try updating your CLI to the latest version with the following command

```
  npm install -g firebase-tools@latest
```

Also try updating the `firebase-functions` dependency to the latest version with following command inside functions directory:

```
npm install firebase-functions@latest
```

As @doug stevenson mentioned above, looking into `firebase-debug.log` in the root of your project you should be able to get more information about the specific error you are encountering.

Comment: The question isn't asking about hosting at all. It only asks about cloud functions.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I have updated my answer now. Once @Ozan comes back on your comment of `firebase-debug.log` will update my answer again if required.

Answer (score 1):

For `Nuxt3` project add this in `nuxt.config.ts`:

```json
nitro: {
  firebase: {
    gen: 2,
    nodeVersion: '18',
  },
  preset: 'firebase',
}
```